# XSLT - encode XML elements as base64 encoded string

Tags: base64, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLT to transform a large XML into CSV and the requirement is to have the last column of CSV the actual XML data in base64 encoded string. I have been successful with transforming to CSV but stuck on the base64 encoding part. I came across this stack overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757414/convert-string-to-binary-base64) to encode as base64 string. I am unable to figure out how to select the entire node and pass it as argument to the template call. Below is sample XML, XSL and CSV format.

**XML**

```
<Products>
  <Product Name="ABC" Description="Sample description" Price="10.0">
     Additional child nodes here...
  </Product>
  <Product Name="XYZ" Description="Sample description" Price="15.0">
         Additional child nodes here...
  </Product>
  <Product Name="DEF" Description="Sample description" Price="16.0">
         Additional child nodes here...
  </Product>
 </Products>
```

**CSV**

```
Name,Description,Price,....,EncodedXML

ABC,SampleDescription,10.0,....,Base64string
XYZ,SampleDescription,15.0,....,Base64string
DEF,SampleDescription,16.0,....,Base64string
```

**XSL:**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="//Product">
<xsl:call-template name="b64:encode">
<xsl:with-param name="asciiString" select="."/>
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the entire node"?

Comment: The product node along with its attributes and all child nodes

Comment: That's going to be problematic, esp. in XSLT 1.0. The problem is not the Base64 encoding, but getting the node back as a string. You will need to construct your own serializer for this - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303127/how-do-i-serialize-output-from-a-node-set-in-xslt-1-0

Comment: @michael.hor257k Can it be done with XSLT2.0?

Comment: It can be done in XSLT 1.0, too - It's just a lot of work. It's much easier in XPath/XSLT 3.0, with it's  built-in `serialize()` function: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-serialize

Comment: @michael.hor257k What XPath expression should I use to get the node to pass to the serializer function?

Comment: If you are in the context of `Product` then you would use `.` (the abbreviated syntax for the context node).